# How to undo 'git checkout -f' to get back uncommitted changes

Tags: git

I accidentally typed `git checkout -f` because I was trying to recover deleted file, but now all the uncommitted files are gone... that's a day of work... Is there a way to get it back? Thanks.

Comment: What does `git fsck` say?  *Maybe* that has something in there for you to reference.  Note that this will help if your files were staged, but not committed; if they were unstaged then they're pretty much lost.

Comment: `git reflog` can only give you things that were actually committed. If the changes were uncommitted there won't be anything in the reflog.

Comment: You're right @JonL; I was thinking of `git fsck`.  That'd help if the files were staged.

Comment: @Makoto It took awhile, but in the end I get a bunch of dangling commit/blobs

Answer (score 6):

You've got about a snowball's chance sitting outside of Dante's Inferno for this one, but it hinges on one ***very important*** step.

### You have to have run `git add` to those files at some point prior to this.

Otherwise, you're ***not*** going to have a good time.

If you have, then you can run `git fsck --lost-found` to recover any files that you've removed.  What you'll get isn't the exact file name, but a dangling commit blob to it.

```
makoto@LATLON-Undefined:~/Desktop/smoketest$ echo "Goodbye file" > badfile.txt
makoto@LATLON-Undefined:~/Desktop/smoketest$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    badfile.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
makoto@LATLON-Undefined:~/Desktop/smoketest$ git add .
makoto@LATLON-Undefined:~/Desktop/smoketest$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at 7124f25 Initial
makoto@LATLON-Undefined:~/Desktop/smoketest$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
makoto@LATLON-Undefined:~/Desktop/smoketest$ git fsck --lost-found
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob 4a503984f4847abd45f4d795d1b74c6482164dcb
```

None of these blobs have any file information attached to them; namely, what file name they are.  But *they're still your data.*

Depending on what you've got on your hands, you could do one of two things:

- Enter into each dangling blob and manually try to derive the file name for it, or
- In reference from [this site](http://blog.ctp.com/2013/11/21/git-recovering-from-mistakes/), you could experiment with their Bash script to pull in all dangling blobs and place them into your current directory with their hash as the file name.

  I haven't personally tested this script, but he does show a video of it working.

  ```
  for blob in $(git fsck --lost-found | awk '$2 == "blob" { print $3 }');
      do git cat-file -p $blob > $blob.txt;
  done
  ```

Comment: You don't need to save the dangling blobs yourself, `--lost-found` saves into `.git/lost-found/other` for you.

Comment: @wisbucky:  Bear in mind that I pulled that as an example, with reference, from another site.  If you have another approach, then I encourage you to post it here as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Check the git stash to see if you had stashed any of those files previously:

   ```
   git stash list
   git stash show stash@{0}
   ```
2. If you had added/staged the files previously, you can try `git fsck --lost-found`. Git will save all the dangling blobs to `./git/lost-found/other` directory (although they will not have their original filenames).

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I accidentally checked out some unstaged changes but was able to find and recover those changes using `git fsck --lost-found` as you suggested. I'm forever in your debt.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a backup system that's tracking file modifications? You could get it back from there. Otherwise you're out of luck - commit more often!